# Temporary variables within JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, oop

```
this.method=method;
function method() {
    var temp = globalVar1 - globalVar2;
    if(temp == 0) {
        //etc.
    }
}
```

I have a method (within an object) similar to above, and I just want to create a temporary variable that I can use to make 'if' statements a little neater, but `temp` is ALWAYS whatever the initial `globalVar1 - globalVar2` value was. If the globalVars are updated, `temp` doesn't update. Thanks!

---

Sorry!
Turns out it was a silly mistake on my part.

### The `temp` variable WILL update every time the method is called.

I suppose this question can be deleted?

Comment: why not `if(globalVar1===globalVar2)`

Comment: That's just a simple example, I've got all sorts of mess happening in the actual one, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 2):

> If the globalVars are updated, temp doesn't update.

You can't make a variable represent a live updating expression.

Use a function instead.

```
function temp() { return globalVar1 - globalVar2; }
if (temp() == 0) {
    /etc
}
```

Comment: Really? I actually have to create a function just to use a simple variable?

Comment: To use a simple variable? No. To get the results of subtracting the **current** value of one variable from the **current** value of another variable without writing `globalVar1 - globalVar2` each time you want it? Yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clear explanation. Can I include that function within the object, or should it be its own thing?

Comment: It is impossible to say what would make the most sense without a lot more context.

Comment: Sorry, silly mistake - the 'temp' variable will update every time 'method' is called based on whatever is contained in globalVars.

Answer (score 1):

Try with removing the keyword `var` from `var temp`.

Put it as:

```
temp = globalVar1 - globalVar2; //i.e. without var
```

If this doesnt work, you have to alter and use `method(globalVar1, globalVar2);` instead..

Comment: That will make `temp` a global, it won't change it from containing the results of subtracting  the initial value of globalVar2 from the initial value of globalVar1.